# I need to eliminate alternate rows of an array

Tags: matlab

I need to eliminate alternate rows of an array, like i have an array of 23847X1 and i need the odd rows and finally making it into 11924X1. It is in .mat file and i want the resultant in the .mat file as well.

Comment: Why would any one try anything any more? no one wants to think or do anything any more. Just post questions and copy answers. World is becoming more stupid all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Try `yourMatrix(1:2:size(yourMatrix, 2))`.

The `1:2:N` selects all elements from `1` to `N` with step `2`.

A more complete example:

```
> M=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
M =

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7

> OddM = M(1:2:size(M, 2))
OddM =

   1   3   5   7
```

---

To load / store data in `data.mat`, follow [H.Muster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351522/h-muster)'s advice below:

```
load('data.mat'); x = x(1:2:end,:); save('data.mat', 'x')
```

Comment: I can understand what you are saying as i have done c++ programming, but the number of rows are really high to be loaded like that, any script to do that and automaticqally save the output?

Comment: @aioobe and H.muster is there any script when i can do without loading it in workspace?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're after, but I use `octave` from command line.

Comment: I have a .mat file whose size i have already defined (23847X1). I wish to eliminate alternate even rows. So the final .mat file is of (11924X1). I guess that be more clear? The way you have done is by eliminating after manually writing in comman window, i was asking if there could be any script by which i can just load the input file and get the desired resultant output.

Comment: I don't know the answer. To clarify your needs and get more attention I recommend you to post a new question, and ask something like "How can I automatically load and manipulate some matlab-data and write back to disk?".

Comment: Say your variable has the name `x`. Then the code is: `load('data.mat'); x = x(1:2:end,:); save('data.mat', 'x')`

Comment: aioobe: Feel free to add the code snippet to your answer so that @MukulJindal can accept it.

Comment: @H.Muster, nice matlab answers you have ;-)